# How to use .in and .out files for testing in a unix environment?

Tags: c++, input, output

I have C++ program, and a bunch of .in and .out files for premade testing. I was wondering how to execute my c++ program and feed these into it.

Comment: Open a terminal, type `g++ program.cpp` to compile. Then type `$./a.out < test.in`. Compare the output with test.out either manually or using `diff` (type `man diff` to know more about `diff`)

Comment: If I have a tar.gz file with several .in and .out files is there a way to run them all at the same time? In one of the test folder I was also given a runtests.bash file. How do I run this?

Comment: There is no way of running all the files simultaneously.  You may be able to run the script sequentially.

Comment: Check if there is some sort of README (or similarly named) file around. Check the contents of the `test` directory, read the `runtests.bash` file, it might contain some clues on how to run tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a list of files like `test0.in` and a corrosponding `test1.out`.  Perhaps you want a Makefile like this:

```
#Put rules/variables to actually make the program

SRC = test.cpp
TARGET = program

INPUTS = $(shell ls *.in)
OUTPUTS = $(patsubst %.in, %.out, $(INPUTS))
TESTS = $(patsubst %.in, %.test, $(INPUTS))

#This build rule is just for showcase.  You will probably need your own, more sophisticated build rules
$(TARGET): $(SRC)
    g++ $^ -o $@ -std=c++11

.PHONY: test
test: $(TESTS)

%.test : %.in %.out $(TARGET)
    @./$(TARGET) < $*.in > $@;
    @if cmp -s $@ $*.out; then \
        echo "PASS: $*"; \
    else \
        echo "FAIL: $*"; \
    fi
    @rm $@
```

Then, just type `make test -j` for multithreaded testing.